# ScrollView does not call onDraw when scrolling in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, drawing, scrollview

Starting with Ice Cream Sandwich (and probably Honeycomb), I observe a change of behavior with the ScrollView.

In Gingerbread, child's onDraw() was called when scrolling, and the clipping rect was properly taking into account the scrolling position.

In ICS, child's onDraw() is never called when scrolling. Furthermore, the clipping rect always contains the full view.

Do you known how I can restore the old behavior?

Thanks in advance,

Sébastien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, will typing the question, I've got an idea and it seems to fix the "issue".

It's related to hardware acceleration. You'll need to override the ScrollView, and in its constructor, disable hardware acceleration, like this :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  try {
    Method setLayerType = getClass().getMethod("setLayerType", Integer.TYPE, Paint.class);
    setLayerType.invoke(this, View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
  } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
  }
}
```

After that, child's onDraw() will be called when scrolling, and clip rect will be fine!